# background image not showing on mobile device properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to get the image to fit the full screen within a mobile device with the code below. On my own computer however it looks totally fine.

```
#topContainer {

  height:1048px;
  width: 100%;

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

#div1 {

  background-image: url("images/Healthy-Eating.png");
  height:1048px;

  margin: 0;
  background-size:cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}



#freeEbook {

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  height: 750px;
  width: 535px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;

}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have edited your question to remove various fluff and particularly a link to what looked like a spammy website. I have also removed the last part of your post which was way too broad to fit SO as per the [help].

Comment: Specifying a height that large is often a mistake. You might want to use % or vh. The problem probably is that a height of 1048px and a presumable width of the average phone (~320 css px) doesn't make sense as a container. So setting a background image to contain in these dimensions may turn out weird. To clarify what the problem is, please post screenshots of wanted behaviour vs unwanted.

Comment: Your code will need a lot of re-structuring to make it resposive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. I will go over all my code and try get it working properly with twitter bootstrap. This is my first website that I have developed so I have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a fixed height of 1048px for your image, `#div1`. This means that the image will always be 1048px high, no matter the screen. That may work for your machine, but chances are your phone screen is much smaller than that! Try the following CSS on `#div1`:

```
#div1 {
  background-image: url("images/Healthy-Eating.png");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-size:cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

`height: 100vh` sets the images height to be 100% of the viewport height.